# SwiperSlide onTouchStart/onClick => trigger slideNext()

Tags: reactjs, slideshow, swiper.js

I want to include this slideshow: https://swiperjs.com/react/

As I find it not very comfortable to drag for the next slide, I want to add an `onClick` event to the full Slider so the next slide comes.

How can I trigger a `slideNext()` in React? I have problems reading the documentation / I do not understand it - and it seems the documentation does not tell how to do this in react.

In jquery it would be something like this :

```
$('section.slideshow').on( 'click', function() {
    swiper.slideNext();
});
```

Here is my react code :

```
import React from 'react'
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, A11y } from 'swiper'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

import 'swiper/swiper.scss'
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss'
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss'

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, A11y])


function Page(){
  return (
    <div>

<Swiper 
  onClick={() => console.log('click')}
  onTouchStart={() => slideNext()     }
>

  <SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>

</Swiper>

</div>

  );
}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can opt to use the `Navigation` API as written in the [docs](https://swiperjs.com/api/#navigation)

```
<Swiper
    navigation={{
        nextEl: '.next',
    }}
>
    <SwiperSlide className="next">slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide className="next">slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide className="next">slide 3</SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-swiper-next-slide-2714t?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 8):

**For React Hooks**

Define a useState like this:

```
const [my_swiper, set_my_swiper] = useState({});
```

Then in your swiper define it like this:

```js
<Swiper 
    slidesPerView={1}
    onInit={(ev) => {
        set_my_swiper(ev)
    }}>
        <SwiperSlide>
            <div>
                Slide 1
            </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
            <div>
                Slide 2
            </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

*Notice the onInit method to bind to your variable.*

Then you can use `my_swiper` hook to call next/previous functions like this.

```
my_swiper.slideNext();
my_swiper.slidePrev();
```

You can call these anywhere to dynamically control your swiper.

Also you can navigate to any slide

```
my_swiper.slideTo(number);
```

Comment: I used the my_swiper.slideTo(*number*) method. Thanks.

Comment: If I could give this answer 10 upvotes, I would do it. Thank you a lot. :))

Answer (score 1):

I used it as below:

```
<Swiper
                        getSwiper={this.updateSwiper}
                        {...params}
                        
                    >{/*modules={[Navigation]}*/}
                        {items}
                    </Swiper>
```

by these functions:

```
updateSwiper(value:any) {
    this.setState({
        swiper: value
    });
}

goNext = () => {
    if (this.state.swiper !== null) {
        this.state.swiper.slideNext();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TypeScript
Imports should be:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import SwiperCore from "swiper";
```

Define a useState like this:

```
const [my_swiper, set_my_swiper] = useState<SwiperCore>({});
```

Then in your swiper define it like this:

```
<Swiper 
    slidesPerView={1}
    onInit={(ev) => {
        set_my_swiper(ev)
    }}>
        <SwiperSlide>
            <div>
                Slide 1
            </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
            <div>
                Slide 2
            </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

Notice the onInit method to bind to your variable.

Then you can use my_swiper hook to call next/previous functions like this.

```
my_swiper.slideNext();
my_swiper.slidePrev();
```

You can call these anywhere to dynamically control your swiper.

Also you can navigate to any slide

```
my_swiper.slideTo(number);
```